# htaccess RewriteRule for 2 parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help with .htaccess RewriteRules. Using index.php to parse parameters and render a needed page.
I have a link ***domain.com?ac=221&co=100***. It needs to be accessed by url ***domain.com/221/100***

I've already made a RewriteRule for ?ac -

```
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?ac=$1 [QSA]
```

How can I add a support for second argument?

Possible url variants:

- domain.com
- domain.com?ac=221
- domain.com?ac=221&co=100

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?ac=$1&co=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ index.php?ac=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```